# JQuery code logic to display checked checkbox not working

Tags: jquery

I have a textArea named as Main Content and below are Two checkboxes

- SMS

  - Email

When a user selects both checkboxes i.e SMS and Email then 
Both SMS and EMAIL textboxes get displayed with the same content as main Content Textbox
with additional feature of having a checkboxes for SMS and EMAIL as 
SMS content same as main content above and Email Content same as main content above.
Please refer to the Fig1 
[image: Both checkbox selected]

These two Checkboxes for SMS and EMAIL are by default should be checked when a user selects both SMS and EMAIL.
However irrespective of the order of the EMAIL or SMS checkboxes Selection, the first selected one always remains 
"Unchecked on SMS/Email content same as main content above" .
Please refer to the next image
[image: error screenshot]

All checkboxes under SMS content and Email content should be checked in case a user selects both SMS and EMAIL checkboxes

**The JQuery code code that handes the SMS and EMAIL tabs is 
The function handleChannelTabs handles the main logic of Displaying Second Imgage with both SMS and EMAIL are selected**

```
handleChannelTabs();
    $("[data-channel-checkboxes]").find("input[type=checkbox]").each(
            function() {
                var self = $(this)
                var contentDiv = $('[data-content-for=' + self.val() + ']')
                var checkedChannelsLength = $("[data-channel-checkboxes]").find(
                "input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
                if (self.is(':checked')) {
                    if (checkedChannelsLength > 1) {
                        contentDiv.children().appendTo(
                                $('[data-tab-content-for=' + self.val()
                                        + ']'))
                    } else {
                        $('[data-tab-content-for=' + self.val() + ']')
                                .children().appendTo(contentDiv)
                    }
                }

            })

    $("[data-use-main]").find("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
        $this = $(this)
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            $this.parents('[data-template-for]').find('[data-main-message-content]').removeClass('hidden').find('.word-break').html($('[data-main-message]').find('textarea').val())
            $this.parents('[data-template-for]').find('[data-textare-content]').addClass('hidden').find('textarea').val('')
        } else {
            $this.parents('[data-template-for]').find('[data-textare-content]').removeClass('hidden').find('textarea').val($('[data-main-message]').find('textarea').val())
            $this.parents('[data-template-for]').find('[data-main-message-content]').addClass('hidden').find('.word-break').val('')
        }
    })

    function handleChannelTabs() {
        var checkedBoxes = [];
        var checkedChannelsLength = $("[data-channel-checkboxes]").find(
        "input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
        $("[data-channel-checkboxes]").find("input[type=checkbox]:checked")
                .each(function() {
                    checkedBoxes.push($(this).val())
                    var self = $(this)
                    var contentDiv = $('[data-content-for=' + self.val() + ']')
                    if (self.is(':checked')) {
                        if (checkedChannelsLength > 1) {
                            contentDiv.children().appendTo(
                                    $('[data-tab-content-for=' + self.val()
                                            + ']'))
                        } else {
                            $('[data-tab-content-for=' + self.val() + ']')
                                    .children().appendTo(contentDiv)
                        }
                    }
                })
        var isFirstTab = true;
        $("[data-channel-content]").toggleClass('hidden', checkedBoxes.length < 2)
        $("[data-channel-content]").find('ul').find('li').each(
                function(index) {
                    var currentLi = $(this);
                    if (jQuery.inArray($(currentLi).find('a').html(),
                            checkedBoxes) >= 0) {
                        $(currentLi).removeClass('hidden')
                        if (isFirstTab) {
                            isFirstTab = false;
                            $(currentLi).addClass("active").css('margin-left', '20px').find('a').addClass("act-a");
                            $($('[data-tab-content-for]')[index]).removeClass('hidden')
                        } else {
                            $(currentLi).removeClass("active").css('margin-left', '0px').find('a').removeClass("act-a");
                            $($('[data-tab-content-for]')[index]).addClass('hidden')
                        }
                    } else {
                        $(currentLi).addClass('hidden')
                    }
                })
    }
```

I have added another code i.e

```
function moveTemplates(onLoad, $this) {
        alert('Inside MoveTemplates 01');
        var changedChannel = $this.val()
        alert('Inside MoveTemplates 02' + changedChannel);
        var divForCurrentChannel = $('[data-content-for=' + changedChannel
                + ']')
        var mainMessage = $('[data-main-message]').find('textarea').val()
        var checkedChannelsLength = $("[data-channel-checkboxes]").find(
                "input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
        alert('Inside MoveTemplates 03' + checkedChannelsLength);
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            alert('Inside MoveTemplates 04');
            divForCurrentChannel.find('textarea[data-copy-main]').val(
                        mainMessage)
                        alert('Inside MoveTemplates 05');
            divForCurrentChannel.removeClass('hidden')
            alert('Inside MoveTemplates 06');
        } else {
            alert('Inside else  MoveTemplates 07');
            $('[data-tab-content-for=' + $this.val() + ']').children()
                    .appendTo(divForCurrentChannel)
                    alert('Inside else  MoveTemplates 08');
            divForCurrentChannel.addClass('hidden')
            alert('Inside else  MoveTemplates 09');
            }
        alert('Inside else  MoveTemplates 10');
        $('[data-use-main]').toggleClass('hidden', checkedChannelsLength < 2)
        alert('Inside else  MoveTemplates 11');
        handleChannelTabs()
        toggleMainAndTextArea()
    }
```

The problem seems to be
Between alert('Inside else  MoveTemplates 10');
and
alert('Inside else  MoveTemplates 11');

The checked value is getting unchecked when more than 1 channels are selected.

```
$('[data-use-main]').toggleClass('hidden', checkedChannelsLength < 2)
```

Is above statement correct ?

Comment: Can u please create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi Somnath , Im not sure how to create a JSFillde. The problem lies in function handleChannelTabs()

Comment: @ronan - go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and add your js there.

Comment: Please find the jsfiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/ebSEW/1/

Comment: @ronan your fiddle is broken..cannot help until you fix it

Comment: This is all my preference, but use `console` for debug statements. `alert` is just...annoying :\

Comment: @dizzieand tymeJV the error is in 
$('[data-use-main]').toggleClass('hidden', checkedChannelsLength < 2)